# What does "juice" mean in pop culture?

Tags: meaning, pop-culture

In Bob Dylan's song, "like a rolling stone", he says, "you only used to get juiced in it".

In a various rap songs also, they talk about "having juice", "being juiced", "juicing [someone else]", "getting juiced up", "getting [someone's] juice", &c.. Googling rap lyrics with juice yields a wealth of such songs. Often it seems that losing juice is a negative experience, and obtaining or having juice is positive.

What does "juice" mean, and why should I juice others or prevent others from juicing me?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Before asking for "meaning", the best place to stop first is at a General Reference...i.e. dictionary. What you are asking for is idiomatic in nature, very broad, and probably primarily opinion based.

Comment: There are many different meanings for the slang term "juice"; see if you can narrow your question to less than a shotgun approach. I'll give you a freebie: in the Dylan song "juiced" almost certainly means drunk.

Comment: Juicing is what happens when you put fruits through a machine that squashes and squeezes them, wringing out the pulp and draining all the liquids they hold. I find it hard to believe you can’t see why it’s a bad idea to let others do that to you!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Obviously nobody wants to be juiced in the literal sense, but this question is about slang meanings. For the OP: one slang meaning of "having juice" is having influence or power, having the means to get things done.